# Load URL without graphical interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, web

In Python3, I need to load a URL every set interval of time, but without a graphical interface / browser window. There is no JavaScript, all it needs to do is load the page, and then quit it. This needs to run as a console application.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `threading` and create a `Timer` that calls your function after every specified interval of time.

```
import time, threading, urllib.request

def fetch_url():
    threading.Timer(10, fetch_url).start()
    req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
        the_page = response.read()

fetch_url()
```

Answer (score 0):

The requests library may have what you're looking for.

```
import requests, time

url = "url.you.need"
website_object = requests.get(url)
# Repeat as necessary
```